# Why do you need two range for loops to change these elements of a vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

For this problem:

> Read a sequence of words from cin and store the values a vector. After
>   you’ve read all the words, process the vector and change each word to
>   uppercase. Print the transformed elements, eight words to a line

This code completes the exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main()
{
  vector<string> vec;
  string word;
  while (cin >> word)
    vec.push_back(word);

  for (auto &str : vec)
    for (auto &c : str)
      c = toupper(c);

  for (decltype(vec.size()) i=0; i != vec.size(); ++i)
  {
    if (i!=0&&i%8 == 0) cout << endl;
    cout << vec[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I was just wondering why you have to have two range for loops in this block:

```
for (auto &str : vec)
        for (auto &c : str)
          c = toupper(c);
```

...to actively change the elements of the vector to uppercase, as opposed to this:

```
for (auto &str : vec)
      str = toupper(str);
```

Comment: [Documentation for `std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper). Notice that there's  no other overload besides the locale one listed at the very bottom.

Comment: You can easily define such a function operating on strings, as long as you don't require more of it than the basic `toupper` function. Mainly, that direct use of it only works for ASCII characters. For general international character support you would need to use wide text, e.g. `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toupper()` converts a single character, and there is no (standard) variant that converts all characters in a string.

The inner loop causes `toupper()` to be applied to every characters in a single `string`.   The outer loop causes the inner loop to be applied to every `string` in the `vector<string>`.

The combined effect is converting every character in every string in the vector to uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

> I was just wondering why you have to have two range for loops in this block:

A `std::vector<std::string>` is analogous to an array of `string`s.
A `std::string` is analogous to an array of characters.

When you need to convert a word to all upper case letters, you will need to change each character of the word to upper case. Hence, you need two `for` loops.

You could use:

```
str = toupper(str);
```

if you implement `toupper` with the right signature. The standard library doesn't come with one.  The version of `toupper` that comes with the standard library can only convert one character.

Answer (score 0):

**toupper()** requires an argument of type **char** and hence you cannot place a direct **string** into it as there is no conversion.

And now,

```
for (auto &str : vec)
      for (auto &c : str)
           c = toupper(c);
```

We are required to do the above thing. I can explain it like this:

1. **vec** is a **vector** and hence is a container, and this container has elements which are **string**S.
2. You can think of **string** as a container of **char**S.
3. Now at the last part of the code, we take each character from the **string** sequentially and turn it into its *uppercase* form.